# Want to display table row data as heading in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have database name "recipee" and table name "contents" in it. In "contents" there are two columns named "id" and "list". I want to display "list" as Heading in html. Table "contents" example

```
**id    list**
  1   Malai Paneer
  2   Kadhai Paneer
```

So, I want to display "Malai Paneer" and "Kadhai Paneer" as heading in html. I am using mysql, php and html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//Open a new connection to the MySQL server
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','recipee');

//Output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$content_id = (int)$_GET['id'];

//MySqli Select Query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, list FROM contents where id = $content_id");
$id = ["id"];
$list = ["list"];



// Frees the memory associated with a result
$results->free();

// close connection 
$mysqli->close();
?>
<h1> <?php echo $list?> </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected output structure should be like:

***********************Kadhai Paneer(as main page heading)****************
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *
*                                                                        *

---

Comment: what have you tired so far

Comment: take it in `<th></th>` tag instead of `<td></td>`, Also show us your html code ?

Comment: `So, I want to display "Malai Paneer" and "Kadhai Paneer" as heading in html.` What does this mean exactly? if you want to use anything as heading then you can use `h1, h2, h3... ` tags.

Comment: It means that when i open the page the page main heading should be "Kadhai Paneer". I want to pick these heading dynamically i.e. from Database.

Comment: show your expected output structure

Comment: loop the results  foreach($results as $row) { ?> <th><?php echo $row['list']; ?></td> <?php } ?>  @nbajpai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Last 10 Results</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1px solid black">

        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <?php
            $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "root","recipee");
            if (!$connect) {
                die(mysqli_error($connect));
            }

            $results = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT list FROM contents");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
            ?>

                    <th><?php echo $row['list']?></th>



            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP is already using `mysqli_*` extension, but you still answered with `mysql_*` extension instead.

Comment: if you don't mind consider this   <th><?php echo $row['list']?></td>

Comment: @jothi nice catch :)

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. Can I change the allignment of retrieved data. I want make font bigger and want to centralize it @mamta

Comment: yeah you can apply styles

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand as what exactly are the requirements. However here are some answers:

1. To show all data as comma saperated heading.

eg:

**Malai Paneer, Kadhai Paneer**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Last 10 Results</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <?php
                $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "root");
                if (!$connect) {
                    die(mysql_error());
                }
                mysql_select_db("recipee");
                $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contents");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
                ?>

                        <?php echo $row['list']?>, 

                <?php
                }
                ?>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why move from `mysqli_*` extension back to the [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*` extension?

Comment: @Raman I want it to be page heading. like we give heading of main page in html <h1>Kadhai Paneer</h1>.

Answer (score 0):

I think assigning the fetched data from your database using

```
$id = ["id"];
$list = ["list"];
```

is not right.

Let's fetch your data by using [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) method:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, list FROM contents where id = ?"); /* PREPARE YOUR QUERY */
$results->bind_param("i", $content_id); /* THIS WILL BIND THE VARIABLE TO YOUR QUERY ABOVE */
$results->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
$results->bind_result($id, $list); /* ASSIGN THE RESULT TO THESE VARIABLES CORRESPONDINGLY */
$results->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULT */
$results->close(); /* CLOSE THE PREPARED STATEMENT */
```

Then, we can echo the result by:

```
echo '<h1>'.$list.'</h1>';
```

Comment: Okay @Logan_Wayne let me try this. Thanks for your reply